# messagebox preventing cursor from changing within WPF code

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

Through out my wpf project I use the following code to change the mouse cursor:

> Me.Dispatcher.Invoke(New SetCursorCallback(AddressOf SetCursor), New
>   Object() {Cursors.Wait})

with the following defined:

> Delegate Sub SetCursorCallback(ByVal [CursorType] As
>   System.Windows.Input.Cursor)
>
> ```
> Private Sub SetCursor(ByVal [CursorType] As System.Windows.Input.Cursor)
>
>     Me.Cursor = [CursorType]
>
> End Sub
> ```

In a subroutine which handles a keypress I check to see if the pressed key was the delete key and if true I use a messagebox to prompt the user to confirm they want to delete the selected entries.

The deleting of the selected entries works fine, but can take some time.

accordingly I call the

> Me.Dispatcher.Invoke(New SetCursorCallback(AddressOf SetCursor), New
>   Object() {Cursors.Wait})

code to change the cursor to a wait icon before the long running delete code starts, and the same code with a value of Cursors.Arrow when the long running code finishes.

However the cursor doesn't change.

I put a console.writeline in the SetCursor routine to confirm that it is getting executed, and it is (both when the cursor is called to be changed to a wait and again when it is changed back to an arrow).

If I remove the messagebox prompt from the equation the cursor changes as expected.  The cursor changes.   I am at a loss to understand why the message box prevents the cursor from changing.

Here is the code with the message box:

> If MessageBox.Show("Do you want to delete the selected entries?",
>   "My Program Name - Delete", MessageBoxButton.YesNo,
>   MessageBoxImage.Question) = MessageBoxResult.Yes Then
>
> ```
>             Me.Dispatcher.Invoke(New SetCursorCallback(AddressOf SetCursor), New Object() {Cursors.Wait})
>
>            ... some code ...  
>
>         End If
> ```

I have also experimented with setting a flag inside the if statement of the message box, and changing the cursor out side of the if statement of the message box.  It didn't work, the running of the messagebox in the subrountine seems to stop changes to the cursor.

I've also experimented with a me.focus command inside the msgbox if statement, but to no avail.

I've also experimented with changing the me.cursor statement to a xxx.cursor where xxx is globally set to be 'Me' at load of the window.

I also tried working with a winform msgbox statement.

The only thing that seems to allow the cursor changing code to work is to not prompt with a message box.

I am using VS 2015 Community Edition.

At this point I'm out of ideas, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: in your messagebox code, if you just do `Me.Cursor = Cursors.Wait` does it work?

Comment: no - sorry, I had tried that too.

Comment: 1) is your `some code` a long running event on the UI thread and if so, is there a reason you're not using a background process instead? 2) Although it's not recommended, you can try doing `System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()` after the cursor change and before the `some code` just to see if the UI updates

Comment: Yes, adding the System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()  exactly where you suggested works!  Thank you very much.  However, I remain at a loss as to why; and as you point out not something that's recommended for a wpf application (although I may have to live with it).  Thanks again.

Comment: ... correction ... this is weird, so the System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents() seems to have nothing to do with it. If when the popup box it appears, it appears over the listview table then when I click on 'Yes' to delete the records then messagebox disappears and the wait cursor is shown. If however when the messagebox appears it is not over the listview and I click on 'Yes' to delete the records the wait cursor is not shown. –

Comment: possibly there's another control which is changing the cursor when your mouse is over it after closing the messagebox? It's hard to say without knowing your entire code...but if it's feasible for your application: disable the form, pop the messagbox, if YES, change the cursor and run your code, then enable the form.

Comment: While disabling and enabling the window did disable and enable the window, it had no impact on the problematic cursor behaviour.   Still looking for a solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91136/discussion-between-rob-and-chase-rocker).

Answer (score 0):

Ok - so its not pretty but to resolve this I ended up jumping the mouse pointer from wherever it is on the screen when the user clicks the 'OK' button of the messagebox to the centre of the wpf's windows list box.

With the mouse pointer now over the wpf windows list box, I then change the icon to the wait symbol and run the long running code.

This worked - showing the wait icon as expect - the only issue is that the user has to visually hunt for where their mouse pointer has moved to (this being the lesser of the two evils - the greater evil being an unchanged mouse icon when a wait mouse pointer is called for).

Here is the code I used to jump the mouse cursor:

Dim MyCursor = New Forms.Cursor(Forms.Cursor.Current.Handle)

MyCursor.Position = New System.Drawing.Point(Me.Left + MyListView.Margin.Left + MyListView.ActualWidth / 2, Me.Top + MyListView.Margin.Top + MyListView.ActualHeight / 2)